# MS Server Insert IF and GeoLocation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert-update

I have 3 tables in MS Server. 1: contains all american zips and geoLocation for those zips. 2: contains stores and geoLocation data. 3: tells me the distance in miles between zip codes and the closest store. If the zip is within 50 miles of a business location. The script for inserting the data into table 3 is:

```
declare @zip varchar (10);
declare @RangeInMiles int
set @RangeInMiles = 50

declare zip_cursor CURSOR FOR
Select ZipCode from dimZip;

OPEN zip_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM zip_cursor
INTO @zip;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

declare @geo geography
set @geo = (select z.GeographyLocation
        from dimZip z
        where z.ZipCode = @zip)


--Select the nearest Postal Codes
INSERT INTO dimZipToStore
(ZipCode, ZipStateID, StoreID, StoreState, DistanceInMiles)
SELECT top 1 dz.ZipCode, dz.StateID, ld.StoreID, l.StoreState, 
ld.GeographyLocation.STDistance(@geo)/1609.34 as DistanceInMiles 
--1609.344 meteres in mile
FROM dimZip dz
cross join dimLocationDetail ld
join dimlocation l on l.StoreID = ld.StoreID  
WHERE ld.GeographyLocation is not null
and dz.ZipCode = @zip 
and ld.GeographyLocation.STDistance(@geo)<=(@RangeInMiles * 1609.344)
order by DistanceInMiles

FETCH NEXT FROM zip_cursor  
INTO @zip;  
END  
CLOSE zip_cursor;
DEALLOCATE zip_Cursor;
GO
```

This works perfectly. 
However, now I must create an update script, that we will run once every 3 months or so. This is for new stores, stores closing, or moving.
What it must do is INSERT (as a new row) the new data if the data has changed, and add an expiredDate to the old entry (this column already exist in table 3).
I have looked all over the web, but can't find anything. I am still new-ish to Tsql, and may have missed the solution. Any leads/help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Added upon request:

```
 CREATE TABLE dimZipToStore(
  ZipCode varchar (10),
    ZipStateID varchar (2),
    StoreID varchar (5),
    StoreState varchar (3),
    DistanceInMiles FLOAT,
    CreateDate DateTime not null default (GetDate()),
    ExipiredDate Datetime       
    )
```

I may have found a solution for the insert after rerunning the above cursor into a temp Table:

```
 INSERT INTO dimZipToStore
 (ZipCode, ZipStateID, StoreID, StoreState, DistanceInMiles)
 select * from(
 select ZipCode, ZipStateID, StoreID, StoreState, DistanceInMiles
 from #tempDimZipToStore TZ
 EXCEPT
 select ZipCode, ZipStateID,    StoreID, StoreState, DistanceInMiles 
 from dimZipToStore Z)
 where TZ.DistanceInMiles < Z.DistanceInMiles
```

Would this be correct? Still having issues figuring out how to update the expiredDate column for the old entry.

Comment: Post your tables DDL. A solution would be inserting your new data into a temporary table (which name starts with #) and then comparing already created records with the newest ones: the ones that don't exist on the old ones are inserted, the ones that do are updated.

Comment: Yes, this is what I came up with. Then I inserted the data into the table using an INSERT EXCEPT statement. I'm still having problems trying to figure out how to update the expired date.

Comment: I find `NOT EXISTS` more readable than `EXCEPT` (and performs faster actually). To update the expired date, you need to join both tables through their keys (set of columns that identify your record unmistakably), and update the old one. If you post your dimZipToStore table definition we can help you with the solution.

Comment: Updated, but the zip code, more than likely, is already going to exist in the table. I only need an insert if the distance to another store is shorter. Then, expire the old entry for the zip, but otherwise make no changes to the old entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something similar to the following. Please review and adjust to your needs. These statements assume that you have the new, updated records already in your temporary table.

```
-- Insert new stores if there isn't one currently by zip code and distance is no more than 50 miles
 INSERT INTO dimZipToStore (
    ZipCode,
    ZipStateID,
    StoreID,
    StoreState,
    DistanceInMiles)
SELECT
    ZipCode = N.ZipCode,
    ZipStateID = N.ZipStateID,
    StoreID = N.StoreID,
    StoreState = N.StoreState,
    DistanceInMiles = N.DistanceInMiles
FROM
    #tempDimZipToStore AS N
WHERE
    N.DistanceInMiles <= 50 AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'there is currently no store for this zip code'
        FROM
            dimZipToStore AS O
        WHERE
            N.ZipCode = O.ZipCode)


 -- Insert the new, closer store (just the closest one)
;WITH DistanceRankingsByZipCode AS
(
    SELECT
        N.ZipCode,
        N.ZipStateID,
        N.StoreID,
        N.StoreState,
        N.DistanceInMiles,
        DistanceRankingByZipCode = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.ZipCode ORDER BY N.DistanceInMiles ASC)
    FROM
        #tempDimZipToStore AS N
)
INSERT INTO dimZipToStore (
    ZipCode,
    ZipStateID,
    StoreID,
    StoreState,
    DistanceInMiles)
SELECT
    ZipCode = N.ZipCode,
    ZipStateID = N.ZipStateID,
    StoreID = N.StoreID,
    StoreState = N.StoreState,
    DistanceInMiles = N.DistanceInMiles
FROM
    DistanceRankingsByZipCode AS N
WHERE
    N.DistanceRankingByZipCode = 1 AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'there is currently a farther active store for the same zip code'
        FROM
            dimZipToStore AS O
        WHERE
            N.ZipCode = O.ZipCode AND
            N.DistanceInMiles < O.DistanceInMiles AND
            O.ExpiredDate IS NULL)



-- Update old record if a closer store exists (it's now on the same table)
;WITH MinDistanceByZipCode AS
(
    SELECT
        D.ZipCode,
        MinDistanceInMiles = MIN(D.DistanceInMiles)
    FROM
        dimZipToStore AS D
    GROUP BY
        D.ZipCode
)
UPDATE O SET
    ExipiredDate = GETDATE()
FROM
    dimZipToStore AS O
    INNER JOIN MinDistanceByZipCode AS C ON O.ZipCode = C.ZipCode
WHERE
    O.ExpiredDate IS NULL AND
    O.DistanceInMiles > C.MinDistanceInMiles
```

On the 2nd statement, we use function `ROW_NUMBER()` which generates an incremental ranking from to 1 onwards (with no ties), which resets back to 1 when values from the `PARTITION BY` columns change, and is ordered by the columns in the `ORDER BY`. So this particular row number will give the value 1 to the stores that have the minimum distance for each different zip code, 2 to the 2nd closest and so on. I believe you just need an active record for the closest one, so we filter by this ranking `N.DistanceRankingByZipCode = 1` before inserting.